# Rotations of a Rubik's cube

Tags: 3d, animation, rotation, javafx

I made a Rubik's cube by arranging smaller cubes. Now I want to apply animations to it. For that I am choosing to use the `Rotate` class and set the angle of rotation and the axis of rotation,like this

```
ar[12].setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);//The array elements refer to the small cubes which make up the Rubik's cube.These elements represent the left face.
        ar[13].setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        ar[14].setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        ar[15].setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        Rotate rotation1 = new Rotate(90);
        rotation1.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
```

Then I am applying the rotations as an animation,like this

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(ar[12].rotateProperty(), 90)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(ar[13].rotateProperty(), 90)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(ar[14].rotateProperty(), 90)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(ar[15].rotateProperty(),  90)));
            timeline.stop();

            timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
            timeline.play();
```

[image: But what I get is this] The inner black sides are coming out.
What mistake am I making and how to fix this ?
Basically, I am getting this for each single cube
[image]
But I need this for each cube
[image]

Comment: You are rotating around the central axis of each individual cube. Instead, you want to rotate around the point in between the four cubes on the side.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. But I am asking how can determine that point? After that I can set the `pivotX`, `pivotY` and `pivot Z` for the `Rotation` object and get my desired animation

Comment: Alright give me a second and I'll write a detailed answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so imagine the image below is the front view of one of your faces on your cube:

[image]

Ugly, I know. Currently when you do `FACE.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS)` you are setting the rotation axis of that individual square to be the center of the square. The black dots in the image below are your rotation axes:

[image]

So when you say to rotate, each cube rotates around that central point as such:

[image]

Instead you need to have the central axis be that point in between all four cubes:

[image]

So, we need to set the axis of rotation for each individual cube to be that center point. I don't know what graphics library you're using but it should be relatively simple to do. Here is a visual representation of the cube's dimensions using `XAxis` as the central point because that is what your code apparently does currently:

[image]

So, for the red square, the x component of the point of rotation would be `face.XAxis.x + 0.5 * face.width` and the y component would be `face.XAxis.y + 0.5 * face.height`. For the blue square, this would be slightly different: `face.XAxis.x + 0.5 * face.width` and `face.XAxis.y - 0.5 * face.height` since its point of rotation is above the center point of the square.

Comment: Wow thank you ! If I further get into some problem I will consult you.

Comment: can you give me a small source code for this in javafx ?

Comment: @DebarunMukherjee yeah give me half an hour

Comment: I tried something like this `ar[12].setRotationAxis(new Point3D(Rotate.X_AXIS.getX()+25,Rotate.X_AXIS.getY()+25,0));` but it rotates obliquely.

Comment: @DebarunMukherjee try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20875499/5087118

Comment: That means if I keep the rotation axis the same (`Rotate.X_AXIS`, and so on..) and set pivot point anywhere on the edge of the cube I will get my desired result ?